# LabView: Boolean Array to Number Block TroubleShooting

Tags: arrays, boolean, labview

I  am using an EV3 Cube to scan a sheet that represents a binary number; i.e a black line represents a 1 and a white line represents a 0.

Using this, I generate a numeric array consisting of 1's and 0's and convert them by using an Index Array to divide them into a single digit, use a quick comparison (!= 0) to generate their Boolean values, then using the Build Array block, I turn it into a Boolean array.

However, despite this, while using the Convert Boolean Array to Integer block, I receive an error which I do know the reason to.

If anyone could help me, I would be greatful! Thank you.

(By the way, I am a Freshman engineering student with no prior knowledge of LabView, just a year of C++ and 2 years of Java to help me. So thorough explanations would be much easier for me to comprehend)

Attached are pictures of my code along with the error I receive.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the error isn't fully visible as it is truncated in your screenshot,
it would help to either have the code or be able to read the entire message.

But what I'm guessing on what I see is, it says that this is Target Specific error Boolean Array To Number function is not supported.

This could mean that a function you are trying to use that normally is available on PC version of LabVIEW will not work on the target platform ( embedded CPU and OS of your EV3 ).